# How do the singular values of a Hankel matrix, generated by some data time series, change when we add/remove rows and columns?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-analysis, singular-values, time-series

Suppose I have a smooth time series $C(t)$ defined on the interval $t=[0,T]$, from which I extract the sub-series $c=\{x_1,\cdots,x_N\}$ of $N$ entries, where $x_i=C(i*T/N)$. Naturally, the number $N$ defines the sampling frequency, and in the limit of $N\to\infty$ we recover the full signal with infinite detail. I can turn this series $c$ into a Hankel matrix

$H_c=\begin{pmatrix}x_1&x_2& \cdots& x_N\\
x_2&x_3&\cdots&x_1\\
\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
x_N&x_1&\cdots&x_{N-1}\end{pmatrix}$.

I need to perform a singular value decomposition (SVD) on this Hankel matrix for different values of the sampling frequency, usually powers of 2. My question is, how do the singular values changed when you go from $N=16$ to $N=32$ for example? Does there exist a clear-cut relation dependent on $C(t)$? Or do there exist lower/upper bounds on the new singular values $\sigma_k$?

I have attempted some proofs but I quickly found out I do not have the appropriate tools in my toolbox to tackle this problem fully.

Answer (score 0):

If you allow the Hankel matrix to be rectangular, then there is a paper saying that the re-normalized leading singular values of Hankel matrix converge to the energy of the high energy state.
https://arxiv.org/abs/2107.01948

Comment: Yes, the Hankel matrix can be of any $M\times N$ dimension, as long as the original signals wraps around $M$ times! I will take a look at the proof, thank you!

Comment: Ok I read part of the paper and I don't fully understand it since it's mathematically pretty high level for me, but I think equation 12 is what I need. I am not sure what $|a_i|^2$ is, though. Do you happen to know?

Comment: @JoJo The scenario in the paper is not exactly the same as what you requested in the question. In your question, your data always come from the same time range [0,T], which is independent of N. And as N increases, the time step decreases. In the paper, the time range is [0, N*dt], and the time step does not change when N increases. Okay let's say what you need is indeed Eq.(12) in the paper.  $a_i$ is the coefficient of the some Koopman eigenfunction in f. [To be continued]

Comment: @JoJo [Continue] In linear algebra, when you have an orthogonal basis $v_i$ of the linear space, any vector $f$ can be written as a linear sum $f = a_1v_1 + a_2v_2+...$. Here $a_i$ are the coefficients. In the paper, the linear space $V$ can be written as $V = V_{NU} + V_{C} + V_{E}$. The Koopman operator K acts on $V_{NU}, V_{C}$ and $V_{E}$ separately. All the eigenfunctions of K consist $V_E$. Therefore for any $f\in V$, you can write $f = f_{NU} + f_C +a_1v_1 + ...  $. Those $a_i$ are coefficients. [To be continued]

Comment: @JoJo [Continue 2] These $a_i$ are theoretical values. The paper says that these theoretical values can be seen by Hankel matrix, which is constructed by the given data.

Comment: Ah I see how it is now. That is indeed different from what I am looking for exactly. Though there are some similarities, I don't see a way to use this directly for my problem. TY for these insights nonetheless!

Comment: @JoJo Hi Jojo, I just found this paper. It has exactly the answer you were searching for, if you know that the singular values of rectangular Hankel matrix are the square-roots of the eigenvalues of the Gramain matrix.  https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0167278989900778 Therefore, as $N\to\infty$, the eigenvalues of the Gramian matrix converges to the eigenvalues of the Hilbert-Schmidt operator for finite $T$.